# Cipher exception when deploying Laravel to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Ok I'm starting to lose my mind here. When I deploy my app to elastic beanstalk I get this error:

```
[2017-12-15 17:50:18] Tylercd100\LERN.CRITICAL: RuntimeException was thrown! The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
```

To be clear I deploy my app source without dependencies installed and with APP_KEY not set, I'm leaving the dependency installation to elastic beanstalk which installs them during deployment.

In my aws .config file I have defined deployment commands as follows:

```
--- 
commands: 
  00init: 
    command: "sudo yum install gcc-c++"
  01init: 
    command: "rm -f amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so"
  02init: 
    command: "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/php-amazon-elasticache-cluster-client-7-1/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so"
  03init: 
    command: "sudo mv amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so /usr/lib64/php/7.1/modules/"
  04init: 
    command: "echo \"extension=amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so\" | sudo tee /etc/php-7.1.d/50-memcached.ini"
  05init: 
    command: "sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart"
container_commands: 
  00permissions: 
    command: "find * -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755"
  01permissions: 
    command: "find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644"
  02permissions: 
    command: "chmod -R 775 storage bootstrap/cache"
  03cache: 
    command: "php artisan cache:clear"
  04key: 
    command: "php artisan key:generate"
  05cache: 
    command: "php artisan config:cache"
  06cache: 
    command: "php artisan route:cache"
  07optimize: 
    command: "php artisan optimize"
```

These commands are running during deployment to aws without any error.

When I go and check .env directly on the virtual machine the APP_KEY is set as it should be considering the commands above.

Yet I get the cipher error.

Comment: Can you post your `config/app.php` especially the `cipher` and `key` part

Comment: Run  config:clear after key:generate - should resolve it

Comment: @Paras `'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you set `APP_KEY` in elasticbeanstalk configuration page in dashboard, there are two things that I would like to point out.

1- When `php artisan config:cache` is run in `container_commands`, it caches file paths as `/var/app/ondeck/...` This causes runtime errors while laravel trying to access the cached files.

2- Cipher error occurs when laravel cannot access the `APP_KEY` value from your `.env` file. If a line like `APP_KEY=${APP_KEY}` exists in your `.env` file, that is the main cause of the error. You assume that `APP_KEY` value is going to be read from the environment configuration made in the dashboard. However, environment variables have not been set by the beanstalk yet somehow when your `commands` or `container_commands` are running. You can solve this issue my sourcing environment variables by yourself by including below command in your commands or files.

`source /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars`

e.g.

```
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/91_config_cache.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      source /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
      echo "Running php artisan config:cache"
      cd /var/app/current
      php artisan config:cache
      echo "Finished php artisan config:cache"
```